# Java JSP servlet 500 error

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dao

I have a Java website, which uses Servlet and JSP and server is my local host. Most parts of the website work well, but there is something wrong when I click "Update patient" button, it shows "500 internal ", and error message is :

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.NullPointerException

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:565)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.focus.DAO.PatientDAO.getAllPat(PatientDAO.java:220)
    org.focus.servlets.PatientUServlet.doGet(PatientUServlet.java:65)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:712)
    org.apache.jsp.common.lp_jsp._jspService(lp_jsp.java:177)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

And here is my "lu.jsp":

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>



<%
    String context = (String) request.getContextPath();
    String role = (String) session.getAttribute("role");
    String id = (String) session.getAttribute("id");
    String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("name");

    String errMsg = (String) request.getAttribute("error");
    if (errMsg == null) {
        errMsg = "";
    }

    String status = (String) request.getAttribute("status");
    if (status == null){
        status = "";
    }

%>


<html>
<head>


<script>
var context = '<%=context%>';
var role = '<%=role%>';
var id= '<%=id%>';
</script>
<!--import DHTMLX library component javascripts and css files-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="<%=context%>/js/dhtmlx/dhtmlx.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=context%>/css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
<jsp:forward page="/PatientUServlet?action=listPatient"/>

</body>


<!--Footer-->
      <footer class="page-footer font-small blue pt-4 mt-4">


          <!--Copyright-->
          <div class="footer-copyright py-3 text-center">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                 <script>
var theDate=new Date();
document.write("© "+ theDate.getFullYear());</script>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!--/.Copyright-->

      </footer>
      <!--/.Footer-->
</html>
```

Here is my "listPatient.jsp" :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
  <%

  String  context = (String) request.getContextPath();
  String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("id");
  String role = (String) session.getAttribute("role");

    //out.println("CALLING main.jsp values: "+ userName +" "+role);
%>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


    <title>List Patient Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script>
    var context = '<%=context%>';   
</script>

<script>
function ConfirmDelete()
{
    var Delet_Confirm= confirm("Do you really want to delete this record ?");
 if (Delet_Confirm== true && <%=role%>=="ADMIN")
 {
   return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<% if (role.equals("ADMIN")) {%>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">

          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<%=context%>/main.jsp">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<%=context%>/common/myaccount.jsp">My Account</a>
          </li>


          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<%=context%>/common/analysis.jsp?">Patient Analytics</a>
          </li>

  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Administrator Tasks
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<%=context%>/common/register.jsp">Register BHCO</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<%=context%>/common/addpatient.jsp">Add Patient</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<%=context%>/common/assignpatient.jsp">Assign Patient</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<%=context%>/common/lu.jsp">Update User</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<%=context%>/common/lp.jsp">Update Patient</a>
        </div>
      </li>

        </ul>

        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="<%=context%>/LogoutServlet" method="post">
          <a class="form-control mr-sm-2" href="#">Your role:  <%=role%> </a> 
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Logout</button>

        </form>
       </div>   

    </nav>
<%}else{ %>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">

          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<%=context%>/main.jsp">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<%=context%>/common/myaccount.jsp">My Account</a>
          </li>


          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<%=context%>/common/analysis.jsp?">Patient Analytics</a>
          </li>



        </ul>

        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="<%=context%>/LogoutServlet" method="post">
          <a class="form-control mr-sm-2" href="#">Your role:  <%=role%> </a> 
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Logout</button>

        </form>
       </div>   

    </nav>

<%} %>
<div class="box-centerside">
<br />
<br />
</div>

    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Patient Id</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Last Updated On</th>
    <th colspan=2>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <c:forEach items="${pats}" var="pat">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${pat.patid}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${pat.pfname}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${pat.plname}" /></td>
                    <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${pat.dob}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${pat.email}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${pat.updatedate}" /></td>
                    <td><a href="<%=context%>/PatientUServlet?action=edit&patid=<c:out value="${pat.patid}"/>">Update</a></td>
                    <td><a onclick="return ConfirmDelete();" href="<%=context%>/PatientUServlet?action=delete&patid=<c:out value="${pat.patid}" />">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<!--Footer-->
      <footer class="page-footer font-small blue pt-4 mt-4">


          <!--Copyright-->
          <div class="footer-copyright py-3 text-center">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                 <script>
var theDate=new Date();
document.write("© "+ theDate.getFullYear() + " University of Pittsburgh");</script>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!--/.Copyright-->

      </footer>
      <!--/.Footer-->
```

Here is my "PatientUServlet.java":

```
package org.focus.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.focus.DAO.PatientDAO;
import org.focus.data.Patient;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class UserServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/PatientUServlet")
public class PatientUServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        private static String INSERT_OR_EDIT = "/common/patient.jsp";
        private static String LIST_PAT = "/common/listPatient.jsp";
        private PatientDAO dao;


    /**
     * @throws Exception 
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public PatientUServlet() throws Exception {
        super();
        dao = new PatientDAO();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



        String forward="";
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
            int patid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("patid"));
            dao.deletePat(patid);
            forward = LIST_PAT;
            request.setAttribute("pats", dao.getAllPat());    
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
            forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
            int patid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("patid"));
            Patient pat = dao.getPatById(patid);
            request.setAttribute("pat", pat);
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listPatient")){
            forward = LIST_PAT;
            request.setAttribute("pats", dao.getAllPat());
        } else {
            forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
        }

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        view.forward(request, response);
                    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         Patient pat = new Patient();
         pat.setPatid(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("patid")));
         pat.setMed_no(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("medNo")));
         pat.setFamily_id(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("familyId")));
         pat.setBlock_id(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("blockId")));
         pat.setCommunity_id(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("communityId")));
         pat.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
         pat.setPfname(request.getParameter("firstName"));
         pat.setPmname(request.getParameter("midName"));
         pat.setPlname(request.getParameter("lastName"));
         pat.setPhone(request.getParameter("phone"));
         pat.setGender(request.getParameter("gender"));
         pat.setRace(request.getParameter("race"));
         pat.setMaritalstatus(request.getParameter("maritalstatus"));
         pat.setStreetnum(request.getParameter("streetNumber"));
         pat.setStreetname(request.getParameter("streetName"));
         pat.setAptno(request.getParameter("aptNo"));
         pat.setCity(request.getParameter("city"));
         pat.setState(request.getParameter("state"));
         pat.setZip(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("zip")));
         pat.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("latitude")));
         pat.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("longitude")));

        Date dob;
            try {
                dob = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("dob"));
                pat.setDob(dob);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

             dao.updatePat(pat);

             RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(LIST_PAT);
             request.setAttribute("pats", dao.getAllPat());
             view.forward(request, response);
    }
   }
```

And here is my "patientDAO":

```
 package org.focus.DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.focus.data.PatientAssignDataBean;
import org.focus.data.PatientDataBean;
import org.focus.data.Patient;
import org.focus.db.JdbcUtil;
import org.focus.util.DbUtil;

public class PatientDAO {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PatientDAO.class);


    private Connection connection1;

        public PatientDAO() throws Exception {

            connection1 = DbUtil.getConnection();
        }



        private static java.sql.Timestamp getCurrentTimeStamp() {

            java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
            return new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime());

        }

    public static ArrayList<PatientDataBean> getAllPatients(){
        ArrayList<PatientDataBean> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try ( Connection con = JdbcUtil.getConnection()) {
            String sql= "select patientid,patient_first_name,patient_last_name from patients";
            try (Statement st = con.createStatement()) {
                System.out.println(sql);
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()){
                    result.add(new PatientDataBean(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3)));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Statement in patients search error", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = null;
            }

            }
         catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("patients search error", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = null;
        }

        return result;

    }
    public static ArrayList<PatientDataBean> getAllUnassignedPatients(){
        ArrayList<PatientDataBean> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try ( Connection con = JdbcUtil.getConnection()) {
            String sql= "select patientid,patient_first_name,patient_last_name "
                    + "from patients where patientid not in (select patientid from patientsassigns)";
            try (Statement st = con.createStatement()) {
                System.out.println(sql);
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()){
                    result.add(new PatientDataBean(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3)));

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Statement in patients search error", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = null;
            }

            }
         catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("patients search error", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = null;
        }

        return result;

    }

    public static ArrayList<PatientAssignDataBean> getAllAssignedPatientsAndUsers(){
        ArrayList<PatientAssignDataBean> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try ( Connection con = JdbcUtil.getConnection()) {
            String sql= "SELECT pa.uid,pa.patientid "
                    + "from patientsassigns pa";
            try (Statement st = con.createStatement()) {
                System.out.println(sql);
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()){
                    result.add(new PatientAssignDataBean(rs.getString(1),rs. getInt(2)));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Statement in patientassign search error", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = null;
            }

            }
         catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("patientassign search error", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = null;
        }

        return result;

    }




    public static int getNameById(int pid){
        PatientDataBean result = new PatientDataBean();
        try ( Connection con = JdbcUtil.getConnection()) {
            String sql= "select patientid from patient where patientid = " + pid;
            try (Statement st = con.createStatement()) {
                System.out.println(sql);
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()){
                    result = new PatientDataBean(rs.getInt(1));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Statement in users search error", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = null;
            }

            }
         catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("patients search error", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = null;
        }

        return result.getPatientId();

    }




    /*New CRUD OPERATIONS START FOR USERS - SM*/


//Join to patient assigns to get BHCO info to check if the BHCO is admin in order to delete
    public void deletePat(int pat) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection1
                    .prepareStatement("delete from patients p where patientid=?");
            // Parameters start with 1
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, pat);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


  //Join to patient assigns to get BHCO info to check if the BHCO is admin in order to update
    public void updatePat(Patient pat) {
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
                 new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        String dob = sdf.format(pat.getDob());
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection1
                    .prepareStatement("update patients p set med_no=?, family_id=?,block_id=?,community_id=?,email=?, "
                            +"patient_first_name=?,patient_mid_name=?, patient_last_name=?,patient_phone_number=?, "
                            +"gender=?,dob=?,race=?,maritalstatus=?,streetnumber=?,aptno=?,city=?,state=?,zip=?, "
                            +"latitude=?,longitude=?,update_date=? "
                            +"where patientid=?");
            // Parameters start with 1
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, pat.getMed_no());
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, pat.getFamily_id());
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, pat.getBlock_id());
            preparedStatement.setInt(4, pat.getCommunity_id());
            preparedStatement.setString(5, pat.getEmail());
            preparedStatement.setString(6, pat.getPfname());
            preparedStatement.setString(7, pat.getPmname());
            preparedStatement.setString(8, pat.getPlname());
            preparedStatement.setString(9, pat.getPhone());
            preparedStatement.setString(10, pat.getGender());
            //preparedStatement.setDate(11, new java.sql.Date(pat.getDob().getTime()));
            preparedStatement.setString(11, dob);
            preparedStatement.setString(12, pat.getRace());
            preparedStatement.setString(13, pat.getMaritalstatus());
            preparedStatement.setString(14, pat.getStreetnum());
            preparedStatement.setString(15, pat.getAptno());
            preparedStatement.setString(16, pat.getCity());
            preparedStatement.setString(17, pat.getState());
            preparedStatement.setInt(18, pat.getZip());
            preparedStatement.setDouble(19, pat.getLatitude());
            preparedStatement.setDouble(20, pat.getLongitude());
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(21,getCurrentTimeStamp());
            preparedStatement.setInt(22, pat.getPatid());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<Patient> getAllPat() {
        List<Patient> pats = new ArrayList<Patient>();
        try {
            Statement statement = connection1.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select patientid,patient_first_name,patient_last_name,dob,email,update_date from patients");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Patient pat = new Patient();
                pat.setPatid(rs.getInt("patientid"));
                pat.setPfname(rs.getString("patient_first_name"));
                pat.setPlname(rs.getString("patient_last_name"));
                pat.setDob(rs.getDate("dob"));
                pat.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                pat.setUpdatedate(rs.getString("update_date"));
                pats.add(pat);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return pats;
    }

    public Patient getPatById(int patid) {
        Patient pat = new Patient();
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection1.
                    prepareStatement("select patientid,patient_first_name,patient_last_name,dob,email from patients where patientid=?");
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, patid);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                pat.setPatid(rs.getInt("patientid"));
                pat.setPfname(rs.getString("patient_first_name"));
                pat.setPlname(rs.getString("patient_last_name"));
                pat.setDob(rs.getDate("dob"));
                pat.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return pat;
    }





}
```

What my expect is that I can get all patient from Database using DAO, and then when I click "Update patient" button, it will jump to "lu.jsp" and in "lu.jsp" you can see it will to "listPatient.jsp" and then print each patient's information. However, it does not work. And then I typed "lu.jsp" in my browser, it also shows the same "500 internal error". Then I typed "listPatient.jsp" in the browser, it shows no error, but there is no patient information in the webpage. So I think maybe I do not grad patient information correctly? what is wrong? thanks!

Comment: Did you try to debug getAllPat method, it is throwing nullpointer

Comment: Where are you initializing connection1?

Comment: which one is your 220 no line in `PatientDAO`? Error message clearly stating that you are getting NPE on that line.

Comment: @Rcordoval I have updated DAO part and I initialized it at first

Comment: @ShafinMahmud  line 220 is "Statement statement = connection1.createStatement();"

Comment: Could you please print connection1 as first statement in getAllPat() method. I am sure DbUtil.getConnection() call in the constructor is returning null.

Comment: Its clear that your `connection1` remains null despite of your initialization in the constructor. Your `DbUtils` might returning null

Comment: Statement statement = connection1.JdbcUtil.getConnection().createStatement(); Try this; if it works it means your constructor is not called

Comment: @Rcordoval, `Statement statement = DbUtil.getConnection().createStatement();`

Comment: @ShafinMahmud You have to say something

Comment: @Rcordoval I meant thats the right line of code that actually you wanted to suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting Error Of null pointer While using

```
getAllpat()
```

Check it first.

Other possibilities to occur null pointer.

```
1. in Session creation or setAttribute() method.
2. in request parameter in servlet.
3. or in dao method if resultset have null value from database it will be not set in setmethod().
```

i thing you have third type of error so check it in your database or in your method **getallpat()**